# How to get a proper value of input variable in react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-applications, object-detection

I am new to React JS. I'm trying to determine a user Target Heart Rate based on user facial expression. The application requires user to enter input of Age and Rest Heart Rate to calculate the THR zone based on level of intensity. For example, the formula of low level is 0.2*(220-Age-RHR)+(RHR). But when I've done the user input calculation, the RHR value didn't successfully being sum into the calculation:

```
function App() {
  const [Age,setAge]=useState(null);
  const [RHR,setRHR]=useState(null);
  const [print,setPrint]=useState(false);

  function getAge(Age)
  {
    setAge(Age.target.value)
  }
  function getRHR(RHR)
  {
    setRHR(RHR.target.value)
  }

  if (print === true){
    var LLTHR = 0.2*(220-Age-RHR)+(RHR);
    var LMTHR = 0.4*(220-Age-RHR)+(RHR);
    var LVTHR = 0.6*(220-Age-RHR)+(RHR);
    var LHTHR = 0.85*(220-Age-RHR)+(RHR);
    var UHTHR = 220-Age;
  }
return (
    <div>
      <thrRange />
    <div className="App"><h1>THR Range Detector Application</h1>
    <input 
            type="text" 
            name="Age" 
            id="Age"
            placeholder="Enter Age here..." 
            onChange={getAge}
        ></input>
        <div>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="RHR" 
            id ="RHR"
            placeholder="Enter RHR here..."
            onChange={getRHR}
        ></input>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onClick={()=>setPrint(true)}/>
        </div>
        {
          print?
          <h2>Low THR = {LLTHR+RHR} to {LMTHR+RHR}</h2>
          :null        
        }
        {
          print?
          <h2>Moderate THR = {LMTHR} to {LVTHR}</h2>
          :null  
        }
        {
          print?
          <h2>Vigorous THR = {LVTHR} to {LHTHR}</h2>
          :null        
        }
        {
          print?
          <h2>High THR = {LHTHR} to {UHTHR}</h2>
          :null  
        }</div></div>
  );
}
```

[THRrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6iTi.png)

Comment: Thank you for helping. It turns out that the value is in the form of String and the sum calculations are actually append the String but when doing the - and * operator it went well with the String value. So I have set up the new setRHR into setRHR(parseInt(RHR.target.value))

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `value` attr. of your `input` tag.

```
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="Age" 
            id="Age"
            placeholder="Enter Age here..." 
            value={Age}
            onChange={getAge}
        ></input>

        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="RHR" 
            id ="RHR"
            placeholder="Enter RHR here..."
            value={RHR}
            onChange={getRHR}
        ></input>
```

It will cause you can't get your value of Age and RHR, so that you would be not to able to finish the calculation.

Comment: Thank you for helping. It turns out that the value is in the form of String and the sum calculations are actually append the String but when doing the - and * operator it went well with the String value. So I have set up the new setRHR into `setRHR(parseInt(RHR.target.value))` and the calculation went well

Comment: If it really helps you, please select the correct answer with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use define a form state like this

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
Age: 0,
RHR: 0,
});

Change events for your fields

onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, Age: e.target.value })}

onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, RHR: e.target.value })}

you can create a form and have the following submit event

onSubmit={onFormSubmit}